# Having multiple classes on a table row

Tags: css

All,
I've got the following CSS for an HTML row:

```
.clickable_row:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
.clickable_row:hover {
background-color: #FFFFCF;
}
```

Then my html looks like this:

```
<tr class="clickable_row"><td>Text</td></tr>
```

However, for the highest row I'd like to add a highlighted class to it as well. I tried to do something like this:

```
<tr class="clickable_row highlighted"><td>Text</td></tr>
```

Then added the following CSS:

```
.clickable_row highlighed{
background-color: #BFDEFF;
}
```

This doesn't highlight the row, any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a space in a class name, you are creating a completely new class, so `<tr class="clickable_row highlighted">` creates the class "clickable_row" aswell as the class "highlighted".

If you want to highlight it, just do `.highlighted { background-color: #BFDEFF; }`

Although, if you want to optimise, I'd probably recommend using the `:first-child` selector, this will highlight only the first row, without you needed to give it a separate class

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.clickable_row.highlighed{
    background-color: #BFDEFF;
}
```

or just

```
.highlighed{
    background-color: #BFDEFF;
}
```

Your selector looks for a descendant of element with class `clickable_row` which is a `highlighed` tag